# Expected field or method name at aapt_rules.txt

Tags: android, proguard, release-builds

While creating release build, I am geting following error :

Expected field or method name at /app/build/intermediates/aapt_proguard_file/release/aapt_rules.txt:289:33
-keepclassmembers class * { *** @{listener::onClick}(android.view.View); }

I think this is due to the fact that proguard rule is wrongly specified.

I am handling onClick event in the XML file as is given below

android:onClick="@{listener::onClick}"

where listener is mentioned inside data tag of layout file

```
    <variable
        name="listener"
        type="android.view.View.OnClickListener" />
</data>
```

Need to know how to write proguard rule to handle this situation.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution? Facing the same issue